# Applying import restriction on specific classes

Tags: java, import

In my program I am allowing users to create Java classes and storing them in a `.java` file within the package `UserInputs`. I then compile, instantiate and object of the class and then call the methods which have been written. However since users can write malicious code, I want to restrict the user created class from `importing` libraries.

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: "I want to restrict the user created class from importing libraries." How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the User created classes for strings "import " + N + ";" and remove those strings, or don't save the classes if they contain those strings and notify the Users about what you did and why.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your program save user code to file. so you can compile it.

Your only solution is to process those lines that starts with import and check the libraries imported.

You should have a list of accepted or not accepted libraries to import to compare with.

Then, if he violated. you show him/her a msg that list the violations.